# How in react to display svg icon from file as inline without making http request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

There is a react application with a requirement to display icons in some parts of the application in an offline mode. The inline svg suits well.

```
import React from 'react';

// inline svg used to show icons in offline mode
export default function InlineSvgBack(): React.ReactElement {
    return <svg width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
        <path d='M20 12H4M4 12L9 7M4 12L9 17' stroke='white' strokeWidth='1.2' strokeLinecap='round' strokeLinejoin='round'/>
    </svg>;
}
```

The problem that in the all the other application for the icons the next approach used

```
import iconBack from '../images/icon_back.svg'

// it handled by webpack file-loader
export default function IconBack() {
    return <img src={iconBack} alt="icon back"/>
}
```

so there is a directory `images` with `icon_back.svg`, currently I have copied it's content to the `InlineSvg` component, however I worry if smbd would made changes to `icon_back.svg` he will miss my React component.

My current solution is to remove `icon_back.svg`. However, I wonder is it possible to make smth like this

```
import React from 'react';
import svg from '../images/icon_back.svg'; // import a line of text

// inline svg used to show icons in offline mode
export default function InlineSvgBack(): React.ReactElement {
    return <>{svg}</>; // output svg line of text
}
```

Comment: You can only have its content by referring to its `innerHTML` (without plugins), but the problem is really in " however I worry if smbd would made changes to ...", you actually should document it in developer guide or just talk to your teammates

Answer (score 5):

You can use the raw-loader to get the svg as text (as you properly already did). After that you can take the text and set it as the html content of a node like that:

```js
import iconBack from '../images/icon_back.svg'; // import with raw-loader

function Icon({svgImage}) {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: svgImage}}/>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (<Icon svgImage={iconBack}/>)
}
```

This should render your svg inside the div tag. Alternatively you could also generate a data url which you pass into an img tag.